# how to autofit columns of csv from powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have powershell script which connects to database & exports result in csv file.
However there is one column of date which size needs to be manually increased after opening csv file.

Do we have some command/property which will make columns AutoFit?

```
export-csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
```

I can't export excel instead CSV, cause I don't have excell installed on my machine.

This is what I have tried latest.

```
$objTable | Select Store,RegNo,Date,@{L="Amount";E={($_.Amount).PadLeft(50," ")}},TranCount

$objTable | export-csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
```

But even after adding PadLeft() output is same, Date column is short in width (showing ###, need to increase value manually)

Comment: CSV files do not carry formatting information, they are basically raw data. How data from CSV files is displayed is entirely up to the software that works with the data. I wonder if that answers you question - let me know and I will post this as an answer.

Comment: Although I am using export-csv, I am keeping file extension as .xls. As per you if displaying is upto software, then how can I acheive what is required to me?

Comment: Don't do that.  If you are exporting as csv, use the file extension .csv.  There are a number of applications that will work better with that info.

Comment: Even if you name a `.CSV` file as `.XLS`, the format remains the same. My point is that the CSV format lacks any means of specifying formatting information. It's basically a plain text document, a list of rows consisting of comma-separated values and that's pretty much all. Due to this, what you are seeking cannot be done using this format. You will need another format like true XLS to add formatting instructions to your data.

Comment: @PeterK I agree that CSV lacks formatting info, regardless of declared filetype.  My point was merely that mislabeling the file type was bad practice.

Comment: @WalterMitty: My bad, I should have used @-style addressing -- my comment was meant for AK47. And you are right, mislabeling is bad practice, of course.

Comment: @PeterK & Walter, Thanks for information, but I don't have excel installed on my computer & somehow I want that column to be autowidth. So any IDEA how I should proceed?

Comment: @AK47: Ok, so now we agree that `.CSV` is out of question. What you _can_ do is to generate native Excel `.XLS` with formatting information. There are a number of .NET libraries (e.g. NPOI and others) which can generate XLS natively, without a locally installed Excel instance. Generally, .NET libraries can be used from PowerShell (see the `Add-Type` cmdlet). You can also use COM (ActiveX)-based libraries (`New-Object`) if only that is available. I am not sure if any of these offer auto-fitting, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you need to increase one of your column sizes all the comments were right about how everything is formatted based on the object content. If you really need the cells to be a certain length you need to change the data *before* it is exported. Using the string methods `.PadLeft()` and `.PadRight()` I think you will get what you need.

Take this example using output from `Get-ChildItem` which uses a calculated property to pad the "column" so that all the data takes up at least 20 characters.

```powershell
$path = "C:\temp"
$results = Get-ChildItem $path
$results | Select LastWriteTime,@{L="Name";E={($_.Name).PadLeft(20," ")}} | Export-CSV C:\temp\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If that was then exported the output file would look like this (Notice the whitespace):

```
"LastWriteTime","Name"
"2/23/2015 7:33:55 PM","             folder1"
"2/23/2015 7:48:02 PM","             folder2"
"2/23/2015 7:48:02 PM","             Folder3"
"1/8/2015 10:37:45 PM","           logoutput"
```

Comment: I tried this, but changes are not reflected in exported file. I tried to export $results.

Comment: I tried this, but changes are not reflected in exported file. I tried to export $results. Please take a look at my questions I have edited it.

Comment: @ak47 the only thing missing from my code is the export. Are you using export-csv with my code?

Comment: @AK47 I added the export command to my answer. In your edit you are not saving the results of `$results` or piping into `export-csv`